# Building SPA frontend without node/npm

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, spring-boot, npm

I'm a back-end java developer (spring boot) and currently I'm interested in building a single page application.

What I like about SPA frameworks (mostly Vue):
Model-binding (saves boilerplate code)
Components and templates (separating code in multiple files is always good, but I don't like single file components as I feel they mix the view and logic)
Routers

However, unless you are using Node there seems to be poor integration
What I don't like:
Node (I develop backend in Java so I don't want to install node just as a prerequisite for NPM)
NPM (I already have dependency management in Maven/Gradle. I actually don't mind it as much, I just don't want to install it and manage it seperately)

I understand why stuff like Node, Npm, Webpack is necessary, it's just that I've already have Java/Spring/Eclipse doing all that for me. I have no desire to have basically two separate build processes.

TLDR: I like the direction and architecture of modern frontend, I just don't want to deal with the tools that are used.

Specific Question: How can I develop a modern SPA using Spring Boot, Gradle/Maven and Vue.js and not have to install Node/Npm/Vue cli etc. What are the best tools if there are any?

Thank you.

Comment: you can unify the build process with maven using a plugin like exec-maven-plugin. But this for build process. If you want to develop easily a vue.js app it is much much easier to use the vue-cli with node. As said there are multiple way to use maven to build also your js stuff and even package it within spring boot. let me know if you need help for that more than exclude Node complitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maven frontend plugin hosted from [here](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin).

It is maven plugin that is leveraging downloading nodejs, webpack, gulp, grunt and running it on your codebase.

You will be able to run maven build and nodejs will be downloaded automatically. It will run your frontend build as well and in resulting jar you will have only necessary minified files.

However, you have to be aware that if you want to debug your frontend application it is a good idea to have those things installed and being able to run the app locally without minification of html and js files.

If you don`t want to download tools you can use [helper scripts](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/tree/master/frontend-maven-plugin/src/it/example%20project/helper-scripts) provided by authors of this plugin to use tools downloaded by this plugin.

Comment: Using maven frontend plugin, would I have to rebuild the frontend after each change, or is it done automatically? I believe angular2 (using cli) rebuilds it constantly. As for debuggin, I'm perfectly fine with debugging in browser...

Comment: If you want to build jar with compiled frontend you will have to rebuild whole maven project. However for development purposes you may want to run your backend application on one port (for example 8080) and then use helper scripts to run local node server (on another port) and enjoy live reloading while developing frontend part.

Comment: If I answered your question please consider upvoting my answer and mark it. If no, please provide more information.